# Heap Sort: Understanding Skiena's bubble down implementation

Tags: java, algorithm

Need help to understand a part of bubble_down implementation:

```
bubble down(priority queue q, int p)
    {
        ￼￼￼int c; (* child index *)
        int i; (* counter *)
        int min index; (* index of lightest child *)
        c = pq_young_child(p); 
        min index = p;
        for (i=0; i<=1; i++)
            if ((c+i) <= q->n) {
                if (q->q[min index] > q->q[c+i]) min index = c+i; }
        if(min index!=p){
            pq swap(q,p,min index); bubble down(q, min index); }
        ￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼}
}
```

What is use of `pq_young_child(p)` and how the `for loop`is helpful?

Comment: Show the implementation of `pq_young_child()` — we can only guess without it. The `for` loop performs test both on the 'youg child' and on its sibling (if it exists) — see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort for more details.

Comment: How is this a Java question?

Comment: I will be implementing it in Java.

Comment: @CiaPan TextBook does not provide the implementation of `pq_young_child()`